# Error with uninitialized variables and returns

Tags: c++

I'm having some problems with my program which I do not understand.
On line 72, I get the error: "error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'sumInEuros' used" however surely it is initialized as I am using it to store a calculation?
Also on line 66 I get "error C4716: 'showPriceInEuros': must return a value" - why must this return a value? the function is simply meant to output a message to the console.

I'm using VS13 and it's c++.
Any help would be very much appreciated, because I am stuck!
Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>         //for cin >> and cout <<
#include <cassert>          //for assert
#include <iomanip>          //for endl
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void processAPrice();
int getPriceInPounds();
int convertPriceIntoEuros(int pounds);
int showPriceInEuros(int pounds, int euros);
int calculateSum(int euros);
void produceFinalData(int sum, int numberOfPrices);

int main()                  
{
    char answer('Y');
    int numberOfPrices(0);

    while (answer = 'Y')
    {
        processAPrice();
        numberOfPrices++;
        cout << "Continue? (Y/N)";
        cin >> answer;
    }

    if (numberOfPrices > 0)
        //produceFinalData(sum, numberOfPrices);


    system("PAUSE");    //hold the screen until a key is pressed
    return(0);
}


void processAPrice()    //
{
    int pounds = getPriceInPounds();
    int euros = convertPriceIntoEuros(pounds);
    int sum = showPriceInEuros(pounds, euros);
    calculateSum(euros);
}

int getPriceInPounds()      //
{
    int priceInPounds;
    cout << "Enter a price (in Pounds): /234";
    cin >> priceInPounds;
    return priceInPounds;
}


int convertPriceIntoEuros(int priceInPounds)    //
{
    const int conversionRate(0.82);
    return priceInPounds / conversionRate;
}

int showPriceInEuros(int pounds, int euros) //
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);

    cout << "The Euro value of /234" << pounds << "is: \u20AC" << euros;
}


int calculateSum(int euros)     // 
{
    int sumInEuros;
        sumInEuros = (sumInEuros + euros);
    return sumInEuros;
}

void produceFinalData(int sum, int numberOfPrices)      // 
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
    cout << "The total sum is: \u20AC" << sum;
    cout << "The average is: \u20AC" << (sum/numberOfPrices);
}
```

Comment: One minor point: `iostream` does already define `endl`. So you don't need `iomnip` for that

Comment: Besides the errors others pointed out "while (answer = 'Y')" is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the `showPriceInEuros` function is not returning the `int` it promises to return in its signature. That's the error.

If the function is not supposed to return a value, you should declare its return type as `void`:

```
void showPriceInEuros(int pounds, int euros);
//^^
```

and then:

```
void showPriceInEuros(int pounds, int euros) {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
    cout << "The Euro value of /234" << pounds << "is: \u20AC" << euros;
}
```

of course.

Comment: Ah thank you, I see where I went wrong with that bit!

Answer (score 3):

You do not initialize sumInEuros in this function. You store a result in it - that's true but to calculate the result you are using the uninitialized value.

```
int calculateSum(int euros)     // 
{
    int sumInEuros;
    sumInEuros = (sumInEuros + euros);
    return sumInEuros;
}
```

Answering the question from below:

I would probably create a class PriceCalculator which has all the functions of your algorithm plus the internal state:

```
class PriceCalculator {
  int m_sumInEuros;
public:
  PriceCalculator()
  : m_sumInEuros(0) { }

  void processAPrice(int price);
  int getSumInEuros() const { return m_sumInEuros; }

private:
  void updateSum(int priceInEuros);
};
```

From your main function you should create an object of this type and give it the prices you want to sum. Do not do any console input from your class.

```
int main()
{
  PriceCalculator calc;
  char answer('Y');
  int numberOfPrices(0);

  while (answer = 'Y')
  {
    int priceInPounds;

    cout << "Enter a price (in Pounds): /234";
    cin >> priceInPounds;

    calc.processAPrice(priceInPounds);
    numberOfPrices++;
    cout << "Continue? (Y/N)";
    cin >> answer;
  }

...
```

You might want to think about adding the numberOfPrices to your calculator class as well. At the end you will do all the operations in your class but the user input and console output outside your class. Your class can be tested automatically this way and is completely independent from the user interface.

Comment: So how would I keep the variable sumInEuros local to calculateSum but initialize it in the function?

Comment: Well, the variable sumInEuros is a state to your algorithm which is used and changed at several functions. The quick & dirty solution might be to create a global variable sumInEuros and initialize it with 0 in your main function - or to make sumInEuros static. Both approaches may cause issues in the future. The right way would be to create a class which has all the functions you use for your algorithm plus the internal state (sumInEuros)

Answer (score 3):

> surely it is initialized as I am using it to store a calculation?

The calculation is based on the variable's uninitialised value:

```
sumInEuros = (sumInEuros + euros);
              ^^^^^^^^^^ not initialised
```

Perhaps you could declare it `static`, so that its value is preserved between calls to the function, in order to calculate the sum of all the values you pass to the function. Usually, it would be better to use a class to manage persistent data like this, with member functions to update and access it.

> why must this return a value?

Because you say it does:

```
int showPriceInEuros(int pounds, int euros)
^^^
```

If it shouldn't return a value, change the return type to `void`.